# Intellij IDEA: Extract method default modifier

Tags: java, refactoring

When I extract some code to method by `CTRL + ALT + M` (windows), new method has private modifier.

Is it possible to configure intellij IDEA in such way that new method will have protected or public modifier?

Answer (score 0):

After press the `Control + Alt + M` a dialog opens and you can configure some stuff like visibility and parameters.

In the visibility section change private to public/protected.

Comment: Аfter press the `Ctrl + Alt + M` I don't see any dialogs. I just set the name to new method.
I want to set have protected as DEFAULT value of modifier, I don't want to change it every time I use this feature.

Comment: what's happened when you select code and then ctlr+alt+M ?